# appcmd disable idle timeout error

Tags: appcmd

I try to disable the app pool timeout with the following command:

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='OPS Apps - v4.0 Integrated x86'].processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:00:00

but it crap out with error:

Failed to process input: The parameter 'v4.0' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=
80070057).

in this case, it's searching by the app pool name, is it caused by the space in the app pool?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Meanwhile you could try with the specific apppool syntax:

```
AppCmd.exe set apppool "OPS Apps - v4.0 Integrated x86" /processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
```

And all the supported properties are:

```
>AppCmd.exe set apppool "OPS Apps - v4.0 Integrated x86" /?

-name
-queueLength
-autoStart
-enable32BitAppOnWin64
-managedRuntimeVersion
-managedRuntimeLoader
-enableConfigurationOverride
-managedPipelineMode
-CLRConfigFile
-passAnonymousToken
-startMode
-processModel.identityType
-processModel.userName
-processModel.password
-processModel.loadUserProfile
-processModel.setProfileEnvironment
-processModel.logonType
-processModel.manualGroupMembership
-processModel.idleTimeout
-processModel.maxProcesses
-processModel.shutdownTimeLimit
-processModel.startupTimeLimit
-processModel.pingingEnabled
-processModel.pingInterval
-processModel.pingResponseTime
-recycling.disallowOverlappingRotation
-recycling.disallowRotationOnConfigChange
-recycling.logEventOnRecycle
-recycling.periodicRestart.memory
-recycling.periodicRestart.privateMemory
-recycling.periodicRestart.requests
-recycling.periodicRestart.time
-recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='timespan'].value
-failure.loadBalancerCapabilities
-failure.orphanWorkerProcess
-failure.orphanActionExe
-failure.orphanActionParams
-failure.rapidFailProtection
-failure.rapidFailProtectionInterval
-failure.rapidFailProtectionMaxCrashes
-failure.autoShutdownExe
-failure.autoShutdownParams
-cpu.limit
-cpu.action
-cpu.resetInterval
-cpu.smpAffinitized
-cpu.smpProcessorAffinityMask
-cpu.smpProcessorAffinityMask2
 )
```